# Oracle Apex 19. How to create form with interactive report from 3 tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I wrote an inner join statment. A table is displeyed but I can not edit FULL NAME from
EMPLOYEES_IMPORT table

My question is... how should I create an intractive form where I can edit all table fields?

Please give me any hint otherwise I will be crazy :(

I tried to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW STAMP_TEST AS
SELECT s.STAMP_ID ,
       s.PERSON_ID ,
       hp.FULL_NAME,
       h.DESCRIPTION
FROM STAMPS s
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES_IMPORT hp ON s.PERSON_ID = hp.PERSON_ID
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT h ON hp.ORGANIZATION_ID = h.ORGANIZATION_ID
```

I think I dont understand trigger function in my example because Im getting an error:

```
create or replace trigger trg_ed_seal_stamps
      instead of insert or update
      on STAMP_TEST
      for each row
    begin
      if inserting then
         insert into STAMPS (STAMP_ID, START_DT)
           values (:new.SEAL_STAMP_ID, :new.START_DT);
         insert into EMPLOYEES_IMPORT (FULL_NAME)
          values (:new.FULL_NAME);
         insert into DEPARTMENTS_IMPORT (DESCRIPTION)
           values (:new.DESCRIPTION);
     elsif updating then
        update STAMPS set
          STAMP_ID = :new.STAMP_ID
          where PERSON_ID = :new.PERSON_ID;
        update EMPLOYEES_IMPORT set
          FULL_NAME = :new.FULL_NAME
          where PERSON_ID = :new.PERSON_ID;
        update HDEPARTMENTS_IMPORT set
          DESCRIPTION = :new.DESCRIPTION
          where ORGANIZATION_ID = :new.ORGANIZATION_ID;
     end if;
   end;
  /
```

So I managed to create trigger and in the sql statment I can update values :)

But when I added a form with a table, apex still can not update values

Error:

```
ORA-22816: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause
```

Details:

```
is_internal_error: false
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
component.id: 14401759410321665
component.name: Process form sds
error_backtrace:
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x4255f33438       971  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_GET_ERROR
0x4255f33438      1039  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_ADD_ERROR
0x4255f33438      1092  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.ADD_ERROR
0x40ffd4e4b0       593  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS.ADD_ERROR_MESSAGE
0x4738108530       547  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_FORM_REGION.RAISE_ERROR_MESSAGE
0x4738108530      1185  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_FORM_REGION.DML_PROCESS_INT
0x4738108530      2198  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_FORM_REGION.DML_PROCESS
0x44b06ce5e8      1246  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE.EXECUTE_PROCESS
0x448c6bff28      2473  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN.EXECUTE_PROCESS
0x40ffd4e4b0       203  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS.PERFORM_PROCESS
0x40ffd4e4b0       450  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS.PERFORM
0x472c9ca568      5726  package body APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW.ACCEPT
0x44b175fb00         2  anonymous block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a **view** based on `select` statement you wrote. Then create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger which will take care about what goes where. All that will be done within the database; Apex will be used just to display values (IR) and "transfer" data to a view (form), while the *instead of* trigger will move data into appropriate tables.

---

How to create an instead of trigger? Using `CREATE TRIGGER`. For example, based on Scott's schema:

This is a view:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp_dept as
  2  select d.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  3  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_emp_Dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        20 RESEARCH             7369 SMITH      CLERK            800
        30 SALES                7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
        30 SALES                7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
        20 RESEARCH             7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
        30 SALES                7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
        30 SALES                7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
        10 ACCOUNTING           7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        20 RESEARCH             7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
        10 ACCOUNTING           7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
        30 SALES                7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
        20 RESEARCH             7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
        30 SALES                7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
        20 RESEARCH             7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
        10 ACCOUNTING           7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

*Instead of* trigger might look like this:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ed
  2    instead of insert or update
  3    on v_emp_dept
  4    for each row
  5  begin
  6    if inserting then
  7       insert into dept (deptno, dname)
  8         values (:new.deptno, :new.dname);
  9       insert into emp (deptno, empno, ename, job, sal)
 10         values (:new.deptno, :new.empno, :new.ename, :new.job, :new.sal);
 11    elsif updating then
 12       update dept set
 13         dname = :new.dname
 14         where deptno = :new.deptno;
 15       update emp set
 16         deptno = :new.deptno,
 17         ename = :new.ename,
 18         job = :new.job,
 19         sal = :new.sal
 20         where empno = :new.empno;
 21    end if;
 22  end;
 23  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing: update and insert:

```
SQL> update v_emp_dept set
  2    dname = 'accounting'
  3    where deptno = 10;

3 rows updated.

SQL> insert into v_emp_dept (deptno, dname, empno, ename, job, sal)
  2    values (99, 'New dept', 1, 'Littlefoot', 'Developer', 1000);

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        99 New dept                              --> new row
        10 accounting     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select * From emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Littlefoot Developer                           1000                    99 --> new row
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) How to create instead of trigger?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer and added some code; have a look, please.

Comment: I tried to create a view but it doesnt work. Should I create a view only with 2 tables or 3? @Littlefoot Could you please help me :)

Comment: View is just a stored query, it can contain as many tables as you want.

Comment: do you know what is wrong with my view statment? I edited my question

Comment: Where are you trying to create it? Should be in Apex'  **SQL Workshop** (or SQLPlus or TOAD or SQL Developer, or whichever tool you use). You can't create it in e.g. report's query property.

Comment: I went to SQL Workshop and tested my sql query and it works but when Im trying to create there a view it returns me the error which I included in my question :(

Comment: If view already exists, try with CREATE **OR REPLACE** VIEW ...

Comment: ok it works :) I will try to do next steps, Thank you very much for your help. You are saving my life :)

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, I maneged with views and triggers but I have problem with apex interactive report with form. Could you please take a look? We are so close to solve this problem :)

Comment: Huh. I think that it is the "Automatic row processing" that does that. Try to disable it and create your own process for DML.**Or**: as this has gone too far (nothing bad about it, now you learned something new), see whether this helps: if you want to be able to modify columns that belong to **only one table** (in that view or a query that uses joins), you could create **functions** that return data from other tables involved. Doing so, those columns wouldn't be "table columns" and default Apex processing should be able to handle it.

Comment: Maybe Im doing something wrong with primary column? Primary key column is STAMP_ID and secondary column is PersonID. Is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207158/discussion-between-anna-k-and-littlefoot).